# how to get list of all users who interacted with my bot?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

how can I get a list of all users who interacted with my bot?
There is a bot that retrieves the list of users using the bot token. You can send the bot token and obtain the users.
so how they managed to do it?

I know that updates will not be kept longer than 24 hours. and
I know that you can't get dialogs as a bot

Comment: So what code are you using? How do you get the list?

Comment: If I had the code, I wouldn't be asking here